# Adding new DbEntities in a referenced project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a base project which contains all the Core models. However, this base library is used by other projects. Now, we need to add new entities from the`referenced` projects so that base library does not have to worry about catering `special needs` of consuming projects.

Now, I came across this link on SO

[Extending Entity Framework Model to include new property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099456/extending-entity-framework-model-to-include-new-property)

Which basically talks about how it is not something supported by EF out of the box and using partial class or inheritance can also be tricky. However, it is 6 years old and I am not sure if EF has new features since. Or if there are more innovative ways out there to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I could imagine with CodeFirst, an (abstract) core context and a concrete derived context might work, as long as a separate database schema will be developed for each of the projects.